# understanding preg_split vs split - No ending delimiter

Tags: php, split, preg-split

```
$gridNumberParts = preg_split( '_', $gridPage);
```

I am getting the error below after trying to swop out all my "split"s to "preg_split"

ERROR Warning: preg_split(): No ending delimiter '_' found

What exactly is this error ? 
Is there another way/better way to swop out the old "split" ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: `preg_split( '/_/', $gridPage);`. You can also use `explode` for this.

Comment: I got explode to work in most cases ! but still would like to know what that error is asking for.

Comment: Read about [PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions)](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php). Your expression is missing the [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Answer (score 3):

The [preg_split](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) takes a PCRE string as first argument (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) which has to have delimiters that define where the regex starts and where it ends, usually you'll find slashes used for this (like so: `'/_/'`) but you can use almost any character as delimiter.

When you use the delimiter character as part of the regular expression be sure to escape it with a backslash or switch to another delimiter.

For example when splitting a path string or an URL and you want to split on every slash you should use something like `preg_split('{/}', $url);` instead of `preg_split('/\//', $url);` to increase readability.

When you use brackets as delimiter be sure to use the opening one in the beginning and the closing one in the end, like so: `{_}` or so `<_>` (both will split on every underscore).

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly is this error ?

[`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split)'s pattern needs [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) to detected the expression.

```
$pattern = "~[a-z]~" ;
```

The first character and the last character need to be the same.

> *A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.*

Then `preg_split` could detects [modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) such as :

```
$pattern = "~[a-z]~Usi" ;
```